# Practical Django Projects - Pages 71 and 80

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, project

I am reading the book "Practical Django Projects". It is a nice book. I have a few questions though :

On page 71, there is the following code :

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
    from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

from coltrane.models import Entry

entry_info_dict = {
    'queryset': Entry.objects.all(),
    'date_field': 'pub_date',
}

...
```

However no variable 'pub_date' has yet been defined in that file !

On page 80, I am being told that I should place two variables DELICIOUS_USER and DELICIOUS_PASSWORD in the Django settings file. I should then call that file with

```
from django.conf import settings
```

Where is that Django settings file ? In C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\conf ?

Answer (score 2):

1. `pub_date` refers to `coltrane.models.Entry` attribute `pub_date` [see the source](https://github.com/clones/django-coltrane/blob/master/coltrane/models.py#L94)
2. `from django.conf import settings` imports your project `settings.py` so you have to define your settings inside your `project/settings.py` file. Here are some docs on the official docs about [using settings in python code](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code)

Answer (score 0):

`pub_date` is referencing a field defined in the `Entry` model. Django will look up the field by name later, which is why it's in quotes (otherwise it would trigger an `NameError`).

In models.py, you should have something like:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    ...
    pub_date = models.DateField(...)
```

The settings file is typically called `settings.py`, and is located in your project's root folder (next to `manage.py`, etc.).